# How to append data from one table to another table in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table of all employees **(employees_all)** and then created a new table **(employees_new)** with the same structure that I would like to append to the original table to include new employees.

I was looking for the right command to use and found that **INSERT** lets me add data as in the following example:

```
create table t1 (v varchar);

insert into t1 (v) values
   ('three'),
   ('four');
```

But how do I append data coming from another table and without specifying the fields (both tables have the same structure and hundreds of columns)?

Comment: Good morning, you don't need to specify fields if the column order is the same as what the new table expects
Consider other options too CREATE TABLE AS (CTAS)
Create Table Like
Create Table Clone

Answer (score 5):

With additional research, I found this specific way to insert data from another table:

```
  insert into employees_all
  select * from employees_new;
```

This script lets you append all rows from a table into another one without specifying the fields.
Hope it helps!

Comment: This is standard SQL, not Snowflake specific, so should work across most of the SQL engines.

Answer (score 2):

Your insert with a select statement is the most simple answer, but just for fun, here's some extra options that provide some different flexibility.

You can generate the desired results in a select query using

```sql
SELECT * FROM employees_all
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM employees_new;
```

This allows you to have a few more options with how you use this data downstream.

```sql
--use a view to preview the results without impacting the table
CREATE VIEW employees_all_preview
AS
SELECT * FROM employees_all
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM employees_new;

--recreate the table using a sort, 
-- generally not super common, but could help with clustering in some cases when the table
-- is very large and isn't updated very frequently.
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO employees_all
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM employees_all
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM employees_new
) e ORDER BY name;
```

Lastly, you can also do a merge to give you some extra options. In this example, if your new table might have records that already match an existing record then instead of inserting them and creating duplicates, you can run an update for those records

```sql
MERGE INTO employees_all a
USING employees_new n ON a.employee_id = n.employee_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET attrib1 = n.attrib1, attrib2 = n.attrib2 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (employee_id, name, attrib1, attrib2)
  VALUES (n.employee_id, n.name, n.attrib1, n.attrib2)
```